# Reading File Name using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a new project, and I would like some help. 
I have a script that I put together and it works great, but would like to see if we can update it

What I need help with is making the batch files read 2 parts of it's own file name and use that to match and replace content of many different .txt files

these are my bat script names, I have made over 100 individual batch scripts

```
(50) Kentucky.bat
(60) New_York.bat
(90) Texas.bat
```

I have a total of 7 different .txt files and each txt files looks like this

```
cmmd.txt
   | Kentucky
   | New_York
   | Texas
   | Houston
```

This is how I setup my script, I'm ok with the setup, it does what it needs to

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "search=Kentucky"
    set "replace=50"
    
    set "SOURCE=%~dp0New Folder 1"
    
    set "textFile1=cmmd.txt"
    set "textFile2=cwab.txt"
    set "textFile3=ecbc.txt"
    set "textFile4=elic.txt"
    set "textFile5=tcpd.txt"
    set "textFile6=uadu.txt"
    set "textFile7=urdm.txt"

    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile1%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile1%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile1%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile2%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile2%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile2%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile3%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile3%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile3%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile4%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile4%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile4%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile5%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile5%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile5%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile6%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile6%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile6%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%source%\%textFile7%" ^& break ^> "%source%\%textFile7%" ') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%source%\%textFile7%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
        endlocal
    )
    
    call "%~dp0\(60) New_York.bat"
```

So this will be the end results after I run the first .bat and it calls the rest

```
cmmd.txt
   | 50
   | 60
   | 90
   | Houston
```

So I would like is to set this up where `set "search=Kentucky"` and `set "replace=50"` are setup by using the file name of the .bat file instead of me editing each `Search` and `Replace`

If you noticed that I added a `call` at the end and it works great, but is there a way for a script to call the next .bat file without me having to edit each .bat file

as you can see, I named my files by numeric order, and each .bat will call the next .bat file

```
(50) Kentucky.bat - this will call (60) New_York.bat
(60) New_York.bat - this will call (90) Texas.bat
(90) Texas.bat - the last one will not have a call
```

Having something like that will help save so much time, since all I would have to do is rename the .bat files as I need them, and that's it

I do appreciate any help and for all your time

meanwhile I will continue to make my .bat files

Comment: So, is the end goal just to rename the files? Sorry, I'm a newbie here trynna understand batch(:

Comment: @ Abraham Zinala - Well the bat files will rename the content of a txt file, using the file name, that is my goal to get to the point that the script will read the filename instead of me editing each batch file, I don't want the file name renamed, I want it to read the filename and call the next batch file

Answer (score 0):

Repeating code is bad (error-prone and hard to maintain). Consolidate and use parameters where needed (where the code differs). This leaves you with just one script and a textfile to maintain the replacement parameters, looking like:

```
50,Kentucky
60,New_York
90,Texas
```

The code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
   REM get vars from csv
   for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ("replacements.csv") do call :replace "%%~a" "%%~b"
:: REM get vars from parameters
:: call :replace "%~1" "~2"

goto :eof
:replace 
REM replace in all matching files:
set "source=%~dp0New Folder"
for %%a in ("%source%\*.txt") do (
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%a" ^& break ^> "%%a" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      >>"%%a" echo(!line:%~2=%~1!
    endlocal
   )
)
```

In case you need it, I included a way to use parameters (commented out with `::`. Use *either* the `for` loop (reading the textfile) *or* the parameters like

```
replace.bat 20 "New Jersey"
```

(both methods support spaces)

See `for /?` for the `~<modifer><var>` modifiers and `call /?` for the `%~<number>` parameters.

Comment: Thank you and like always great work, this will help me with other projects, but for this project we are missing the .txt files, maybe I didn't explain right in my question, let me try again

Comment: If you mean `scripts read it's own file name`, then `%~n0` should do (without extension). `%~nx0` with extension.

Comment: Once Again Thank you - But we are still missing the txt files, and I'm replacing `%~1` with `%~n0` yes - the Batch file is to read it's own name so that it can edit 7 different txt files, the batch file's name is found within the 7 txt files, the batch file numbers will replace the name, hope that makes sense

Comment: @Compo - do you think you can help me, based on my question, the bat files need to be able read it's own file name, and then edit those files I mentioned, and is there a way to make the call automatically call the next batch in numerical order

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But extracting the search/replace strings from the script name and searching for the next script results in many *exactly identical* scripts with just different names. To use it this way is an alien concept for me (done successfully just for the challenge). Just one script (taking the search/replace pairs per parameters or using a search/replace text file) is a much more efficient method (also done successfully). Let me know which method you are more interested in.

Comment: I was thinking the same, doing the Alien way as I have done, caused me to make over 300 scripts, I was thinking 1 script that will find a Search.txt file that will have all my listed file names in it, and it scans all the other txt files for the replacement, I think this way will be best, I will update my question

Comment: Makes sense. I changed my answer accordingly. If it's too slow, google for `jrepl.bat` for the replacement part.

Comment: I'm good with slow, my original scripts took 30 sec each, and it does work, now I'm going to reverse the script as well, I only mention one method, because I knew I would be able to reverse it, so my task is change numbers to names, and later on names to new numbers, once again Thank you

Comment: reversing now is just a matter of changing the  textfile format from `number,string` to `string,number`

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, Thanks again

Comment: Well it looks like reversing will not work, it can't find the exact match, for example I have 50, and 2050, both 50 get updated

Comment: it doesn't even work with my original script, well now I need to see how to reverse it with exact match

Comment: OK, using my old script I added a comma at the end and a space before the numbers in the search filed, `set "replace= 50,"` now I can reverse. Could doing something like this work on the csv file

Comment: Take a look at [jrepl.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It supports full REGEX support for search and replacement.

Comment: OK, Thank you for all the support